# How are mods selected?

Tags: discussion, election

I was asked if I wanted to throw my hat in. No. I am a newbie and shocked it was just based on points. I have 706. The rep needed should be way higher! What I want to know is, 1) are current mods up for reelection or secure in their positions? 2) Do you have to nominate yourself or can you nominate someone else? Again 706, I will let you decide, but I am curious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This election is to add one moderator to the existing team; no moderators are being replaced.

Candidates must self-nominate.  If there is somebody you think would be a good candidate, you'll need to ask that person to nominate.  Chat is a good place to do that.

While SE only requires 300 reputation to stand in an election, the *practical* limit tends to be a lot higher, as you've noticed.  But better to set a lower boundary and let each community decide than to set a higher one and shut out people who, under some circumstances on some sites, would be good candidates.  Throwing your hat into the ring is relatively easy; persuading the community to elect you is the bigger challenge.

Comment: thanks, I think I would like others to nominate mods simply because many great people would be too modest to put themselves forward... but have no probkem with whatever pleases the majority.

Comment: @WillowRex please encourage those people to self-nominate.  It's happened before; I wasn't going to stand on The Workplace but people nudged me so I reconsidered.

Comment: If I ever have someone in mind, I would.

Comment: I stood in the SU election cause a bunch of good folks kept bothering the mods about when the next election would be, cause I'd make a good mod. So, totally bug anyone who you think would be a good mod ;)

Answer (score 1):

Although I have been here for a while now and kind of familiar with the place, I still don't know answers to some of the questions you have asked. (I am more concerned with answering people's questions to the best of my knowledge, instead of learning the mechanics of this site). I will still try to answer your questions to the best of my knowledge.

AFAIK:

1- The current mods are not up for re-election, this election is just here to add one person to the group.

2- You have to nominate yourselves. You cannot nominate anyone else. Although I would love it to be so that nobody can nominate themselves and people could only nominate others. That would help produce more productive mods with higher member support.

3- Although it is not a part of your question, but I should add in that 706 rep means that you know how the site works. That is enough for your experience with the site working, to serve as a mod, if you want to run for it. Also, while 706 is indeed very low rep, considering that the site is run by the community (or so we like to believe), if the community wants a 300 rep mod, why not?!

Comment: As Monica pointed out, the current mods are here to stay.

Comment: Yeh, thanks for the correction man. I'd have much appreciated if you could have edited my answer and removed the misleading part.

Comment: Editing is actually a lot more restrictive on meta than on main; I'm not sure exactly where the boundaries are, but I know I've been in the situation where I could edit on main but not on meta.  In those cases all you can do is leave a comment so the author can edit.

Comment: @MonicaCellio The limit looks to be somewhere between 1,000 rep and 2,000 rep. I can edit on [Server Fault Meta](https://meta.serverfault.com/), where I have 2,478 rep at present, but not at [meta.scifi.se], where I have 1,115 rep right now. The only accounts I have between those levels are on beta sites, which have very different reputation limits.

Comment: why not edit yourself? Unless you do not know how. I had that problem in the beginning, but it helps to say that you don't know and ask how.

Comment: Seems like I can actually edit now! Must be at 2k because last time I checked I couldn't.

Comment: @YoustayIgo In general it's considered bad manners to change the actual meaning of someone's post (as opposed to just improving the presentation). That's why corrections are normally done in comments first rather than as edits. Quite apart from anything else the correction may be wrong and the OP may be able to reply explaining why.